Flask is page can not be visted outside of container but works inside (using curl to test in container)
I have a Python Flask application running in a docker container, I try to access it from the localhost using cURL, the error returned is curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer, when I use cURL within the container (docker exec) it works fine, outside, the mentioned error occurs.
My code is a bit too long so, I will just tell you, it has what you would expect:
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=1111)

My Dockerfile:
FROM python:latest
WORKDIR /home/administrator/DirectoyHidden
COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .


EXPOSE 1111
CMD ["python", "main.py"]


My Run Command:
docker run -d -v volumehidden:/home/administrator/directoryhidden -p 1111:1111 imagehidden

I tried changing the python versions and the docker file a bit, still having the same error.

Often, your program will say what address and port it listens on in the logs. Can you check if it says 0.0.0.0:1111 or 127.0.0.1:1111, please? (using docker logs <container name>)

in the logs it says 127.0.0.1:1111 even thought I set it to 0.0.0.0

Does this help: https://serverfault.com/questions/769578/curl-56-recv-failure-connection-reset-by-peer-when-hitting-docker-container

Ah, I tried the solution in that post and it did not work.

@HansKilian I tried using the flask run command instead of python main.py and it worked! For some reason the flask.run() function was not setting the host, but everything is fine now! But you will now need to post a question so I can close this topic!

I don't understand why your app.run approach doesn't work, so I don't feel qualified to write an answer. But I've seen other people have the issue, so that's why I asked you to check the logs. If you can write a good answer yourself, you should do that.
